# How to calculate time dilation for a space traveller travelling to a star which is moving away from the Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

I understand how to calculate the dilated time when travelling to a star, but none of the formulas I know take the recessional velocity of the star into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This is less complicated than you think. Remember that if we on Earth measure the time taken for the trip as $t$ then the astronauts on board the spaceship measure the time as:

$$ \tau = \frac{t}{\gamma} $$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor. So all you have to do is calculate the time, $t$, taken for the spaceship to reach the star *as measured in the Earth frame*. Then divide by $\gamma$ to get the time recorded on the astronauts' clock.

[image: Chasing a star]

I'll leave you to do the calculation of $t$ since it's simple kinetics.

Comment: Isn't the recessional velocity of the star constantly increasing as it moves further away though? like Hubble's law shows: recessional velocity = Ho.D

Comment: @KeithWells: if you want to include the affects due to the expansion of the universe then the problem becomes harder by several orders of magnitude. That's because the expansion of the universe is not constant. Indeed there will be some initial conditions for which the rocket cannot ever reach the star. You also need to account for the changes in the velocity of the rocket due to the expansion of the universe, so the Lorentz factor of the rocket will change with time.

Comment: Could it be done by developing a function for recessional velocity over time, and using this function as 'u' in the diagram in your answer?

Comment: Yes, kind of, but it isn't a simple function and the rocket and star velocities will change in different ways. In effect you are calculating the geodesics of the rocket and star and working out where they intersect. That's a hard problem.

Comment: I've developed an exponential function for the stars velocity, and im going to assume the rockets velocity remains constant. How should I go about finding the time taken for the rocket to reach the star and the distance covered by the rocket?